# Why is my UI app not working when nested in a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to adapt a [UI app](http://codepen.io/supah/pen/WwoYjO) built by codepen user Fabio Ottaviani by taking it's basic functionality and placing it inside a bootstrap modal. If it's removed from the modal it works fine but when placed in the modal it works the first time and then breaks once it is reset. The courser doesn't even become a pointer/hand once the UI is reset.

```js
var $play = $('.play'),
    $detail  = $('.detail'),
    $movie = $('.movie', $detail),
    $close = $('.close');

$('.movies .movie').click(function(){
  $movie.html($(this).html());
  $play.appendTo($movie);

  $poster = $('.poster', this).addClass('active');

  $('.poster', $detail).css({
    top: $poster.position().top,
    left: $poster.position().left,
    width: $poster.width(),
    height: $poster.height()
  }).data({
    top: $poster.position().top,
    left: $poster.position().left,
    width: $poster.width(),
    height: $poster.height()
  })

  $detail.show();

  $('.poster', $detail).delay(10).queue(function(next) {
    $detail.addClass('ready');

    next();
  }).delay(100).queue(function(next){
    $(this).css({
      top: '-10%',
      left: '-6%',
      width: 266,
      height: 400
    });
    next();
  })
})


/*--------------------
Close
--------------------*/
function close(){
  console.log('asd');
  $p = $('.detail .poster');
  console.log($p)
  $p.css({
    top: $p.data('top'),
    left: $p.data('left'),
    width: $p.data('width'),
    height: $p.data('height'),
  })
  $detail.removeClass('ready').delay(500).queue(function(next){
    $(this).hide();
    $poster.removeClass('active');
    next();
  });
}

$close.click(close);
$('body').click(function(e){
  $p = $(e.target).parents();
  if ($p.is('.app')){
    return false;
  } else {
    close();
  }
})
```

```css
/***********reset.css************/
div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,svg,symbol,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    font-size:100%;
    font:inherit;
    vertical-align:baseline;
}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{
    display:block;
}
body {line-height:1;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style:none 
}
blockquote,q{
    quotes:none;
}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{ 
    content:''; content:none;
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}


/************style.css************/
/*--------------------
App
--------------------*/

.app h2 {
  color: #525661;
  font-size: 17px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 20px 28px 0;
  margin: -6px 0 0 0;
}

/*--------------------
Movies
--------------------*/
.movies {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 18px;
}
.movies .movie {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.movies .movie .poster {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.movies .movie .poster.active {
  opacity: 0;
}
.movies .movie .title {
  color: #525661;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.movies .movie .info {
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: .8;
}
.movies .movie .desc {
  display: none;
}

/*--------------------
Detail
--------------------*/
.detail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 37px 30px 30px 255px;
  display: none;
}
.detail::before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.13, 0.1, 0.81);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.13, 0.1, 0.81);
}
.detail .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 22px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 6px solid #FFF;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  z-index: 10;
}
.detail .poster {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: -10%;
  left: -6%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.13, 0.1, 0.81);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.13, 0.1, 0.81);
}
.detail .title,
.detail .info,
.detail .desc,
.detail .play,
.detail .close {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
          transform: translateX(-50px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.13, 0.1, 0.81);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.13, 0.1, 0.81);
}
.detail .close {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
          transform: translateX(10px);
}
.detail .title {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #525661;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.detail .info {
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.detail .desc {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
.detail .play {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #E4761F, #FF8B32);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #E4761F, #FF8B32);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 8px 17px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 -2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 10;
  outline: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}
.detail .play svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.detail.ready::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.detail.ready .info {
  opacity: .8;
}
.detail.ready .poster {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
          transition-duration: .5s;
}
.detail.ready .title,
.detail.ready .info,
.detail.ready .desc,
.detail.ready .play,
.detail.ready .close {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
          transition-duration: .5s;
}
.detail.ready .title {
  -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
          transition-delay: .2s;
}
.detail.ready .info {
  -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
          transition-delay: .3s;
}
.detail.ready .desc {
  -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
          transition-delay: .4s;
}
.detail.ready .play {
  -webkit-transition-delay: .5s;
          transition-delay: .5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <!--modal-->
    <script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
        /* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree needs access to the styles and they must be inlined if they are on local disk! */
        
        .modal-open body {
            -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
            -moz-filter: blur(1px);
            filter: blur(1px);
        }
        
        .modal-dialog .modal-content {
            border-radius: 0;
            box-shadow: none;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
            padding-left: 30px;
            padding-right: 30px;
        }
        
        .modal-backdrop {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        }
        
        .columns {
            column-count: 3;
            column-gap: 20px;
        }
        
        img {
            width: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>


    <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">




</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Open Modal</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <div class="app">

                        <legend>Most Popular Movies</legend>
                        <section class="movies">
                            <div class="movie">
                                <img src="http://movium.io/data/posters/eqFckcHuFCT1FrzLOAvXBb4jHwq.jpg" alt="" class="poster" />
                                <div class="title">Room</div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span class="length">117 min</span>
                                    <span class="year">2015</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    Jack is a young boy of 5 years old who has lived all his life in one room. He believes everything within it are the only real things in the world. But what will happen when his Ma suddenly tells him that there are other things outside of Room?
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="movie">
                                <img src="http://movium.io/data/posters/lIv1QinFqz4dlp5U4lQ6HaiskOZ.jpg" alt="" class="poster" />
                                <div class="title">Whiplash</div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span class="length">167 min</span>
                                    <span class="year">2015</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    Under the direction of a ruthless instructor, a talented young drummer begins to pursue perfection at any cost, even his humanity.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="movie">
                                <img src="http://movium.io/data/posters/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg" alt="" class="poster" />
                                <div class="title">Mad Max</div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span class="length">120 min</span>
                                    <span class="year">2015</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    An apocalyptic story set in the furthest reaches of our planet, in a stark desert landscape where humanity is broken, and most everyone is crazed fighting for the necessities of life. Within this world exist two rebels on the run who just might be able to restore order. There's Max, a man of action and a man of few words, who seeks peace of mind following the loss of his wife and child in the aftermath of the chaos.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="movie">
                                <img src="http://movium.io/data/posters/5W794ugjRwYx6IdFp1bXJqqMWRg.jpg" alt="" class="poster" />
                                <div class="title">The Revenant</div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span class="length">156 min</span>
                                    <span class="year">2015</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    In the 1820s, a frontiersman, Hugh Glass, sets out on a path of vengeance against those who left him for dead after a bear mauling.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        <div class="detail">
                            <svg class="close">
                                <use xlink:href="#close"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <div class="movie">

                                <img src="http://movium.io/data/posters/eqFckcHuFCT1FrzLOAvXBb4jHwq.jpg" alt="" class="poster" />
                                <div class="title">Room</div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span class="length">117 min</span>
                                    <span class="year">2015</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    Jack is a young boy of 5 years old who has lived all his life in one room. He believes everything within it are the only real things in the world. But what will happen when his Ma suddenly tells him that there are other things outside of Room?
                                </div>

                                <button class="play">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewbox="0 0 232.153 232.153" style="enable-background:new 0 0 232.153 232.153;" xml:space="preserve" width="10px" height="10px">
                                        <g id="Play">
                                            <path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;" d="M203.791,99.628L49.307,2.294c-4.567-2.719-10.238-2.266-14.521-2.266   c-17.132,0-17.056,13.227-17.056,16.578v198.94c0,2.833-0.075,16.579,17.056,16.579c4.283,0,9.955,0.451,14.521-2.267   l154.483-97.333c12.68-7.545,10.489-16.449,10.489-16.449S216.471,107.172,203.791,99.628z" fill="#FFFFFF" />
                                        </g>
                                    </svg> play movie
                                </button>



                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->




    <!-- Icons -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display:none;">
        <symbol id="close" viewbox="0 0 212.982 212.982">
            <g>
                <path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;" d="M131.804,106.491l75.936-75.936c6.99-6.99,6.99-18.323,0-25.312   c-6.99-6.99-18.322-6.99-25.312,0l-75.937,75.937L30.554,5.242c-6.99-6.99-18.322-6.99-25.312,0c-6.989,6.99-6.989,18.323,0,25.312   l75.937,75.936L5.242,182.427c-6.989,6.99-6.989,18.323,0,25.312c6.99,6.99,18.322,6.99,25.312,0l75.937-75.937l75.937,75.937   c6.989,6.99,18.322,6.99,25.312,0c6.99-6.99,6.99-18.322,0-25.312L131.804,106.491z" fill="#525661" />
            </g>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="ico-search">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#363a47" d="M14.769,14.769c-0.342,0.342-0.896,0.342-1.237,0l-3.756-3.756
                                                                    c-2.399,1.793-5.801,1.623-7.981-0.557c-2.392-2.392-2.392-6.271,0-8.663s6.271-2.392,8.662,0c2.18,2.181,2.35,5.583,0.557,7.981
                                                                    l3.756,3.756C15.11,13.873,15.11,14.427,14.769,14.769z M9.219,3.032c-1.709-1.709-4.479-1.709-6.188,0
                                                                    c-1.708,1.708-1.708,4.479,0,6.188c1.709,1.708,4.479,1.708,6.188,0C10.927,7.51,10.927,4.74,9.219,3.032z" />
        </symbol>
    </svg>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scoping issue. When looking at the console log for the app, I notice the error

`$poster is undefined`

When looking at your code I see $poster is being set to something, but is scoped to the `$('.movies .movie')` click function. Everything outside of that function that needs to use it, doesn't know what it is.

The fix to this would be adding `$poster` to your global variables at the top

`var $play = $('.play'),
    $detail  = $('.detail'),
    $movie = $('.movie', $detail),
    $close = $('.close'),
    $poster;`

Comment: This solved my problem although I actually had to define                 `$poster =$('.poster')` to get it to work. I actually realized I hadn't looked a the console log for errors later on. Guess I figured it was fine because it worked otherwise.